# ionic [Error]Cannot find name 'platform'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.platform'?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Iam trying to create a login page that redirects to a map page. I get the error Cannot find name 'platform'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.platform'? in the platform.ready().then(() => { function. Please Help! i have tried using this.platform and has not worked either. Thank you

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { RideListPage } from '../pages/ride-list/ride-list';
import { AuthPage } from '../pages/auth/home/home';
import { DataProvider } from '../providers/data';
import { AuthProvider } from '../providers/auth';

export interface PageInterface {
  title: string;
  component: any;
  icon: string;
  logsOut?: boolean;
  index?: number;
  tabComponent?: any;
}

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.template.html',
})
export class TaxiApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  isAppInitialized: boolean = false;
  user: any;
  rootPage: any = AuthPage

  appPages: PageInterface[] = [
    {title: 'Map', component: HomePage, index: 1, icon: 'map'},
    {title: 'Taxi rides', component: RideListPage, index: 2, icon: 'car'},
    {title: 'About', component: AboutPage, index: 3, icon: 'information-circle'},
  ];


  constructor(private platform:Platform,protected data: DataProvider,
    protected auth: AuthProvider) {
    this.user = {
      image: ''
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.auth.getUserData().subscribe(data => {
        if (!this.isAppInitialized) {
          this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
          this.isAppInitialized = true;
        }
        this.user = data;
        this.data.list('pets').subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }, err => {
        this.nav.setRoot(AuthPage);
      });
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    // Call any initial plugins when ready
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
      // https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
      // The cordova.InAppBrowser.open() function is defined to be a drop-in replacement for the window.open()
      // function. Existing window.open() calls can use the InAppBrowser window, by replacing window.open:
      if ((<any>window).cordova && (<any>window).cordova.InAppBrowser) {
        window.open = (<any>window).cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
      }

    });
  }

  openPage(page: PageInterface) {
    // the nav component was found using @ViewChild(Nav)
    // reset the nav to remove previous pages and only have this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    if (page.index) {
      this.nav.setRoot(page.component, { tabIndex: page.index });
    } else {
      this.nav.setRoot(page.component).catch(() => {
        console.log("Didn't set nav root");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error if you use this.platform?

Comment: Argument of type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(reason: any) => PromiseLike<never>'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' provides no match for the signature '(reason: any): PromiseLike<never>'.

Comment: It is in _your second call_ .. you forgot `this` here: `platform.ready().then(() => {`. Why are you calling twice?